# How do I stop Outlook from stealing mailto protocol from Gmail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2010, mailto

In Chrome, when I click on a mailto: link, I'd like to be taken to my Gmail's Compose window.  So I downloaded [ChromeMailer](http://www.skaelede.hu/?e=chromemailer_installed&lg=en) and it works relatively well.  However, after using Outlook 2010, the default for the mailto reverts to Outlook.

I went into Outlook's `Options`, clicked `Default Programs...` and was greeted with this:

[image]

As you can see, the checkbox is grayed out and I can't do anything to changed it.  Clicking `Select All` checkbox does nothing either.

How do I stop Outlook from stealing the mailto protocol handler?

Comment: (this is a joke, if you can't handle it, please, press ctrl+w) Go find developers that wrote outlook and harass them (legally) with [various gardening tools] to stop being [unflattering insults here]. PS - I find this very "interesting" behavior. Maybe you can write a script that's called as a scheduled task to assert the association you prefer.

Comment: This is probably because Outlook does not see any other programs on the computer for handling any of these types.

Comment: @msuic2myear: I thought he said that the ChomeMailer established the mailto protocol default? Sounds like Outlook isn't asking before overwriting a default, which is my definition of political-programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the association of mailto in the registry by going to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command
```

and change it from Outlook to Chrome composer

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" https://mail.google.com/mail/?=1#compose
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use GMail for the links in Chrome, the '[Send from GMail'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc) extension works well for me on a machine that has both Outlook and Thunderbird installed.